# jquery ajax sending data

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

```
contentType: "text/html; charset=utf-8",
url:"secret.aspx?plu="+$("#Text1").val()+"&gh="+$("#TextBox1").val()+"&sid="+$("#TextBox2").val(),
processData: false,
dataType: "html",
 success: function(data)
```

is it the above syntax correct to send the data
recieved by the code below

```
string sid=Request.QueryString["sid"];
string id = Request.QueryString["plu"];
int ide =Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["gh"]);
Response.write(sid);
Response.end();
```

or is there any other way to achieve the same

Comment: Did you run it and try?

Comment: yupp,not working@jonesy

Answer (score 1):

The only problem with that request is that it will break if you have any special characters in your input values.

A solution to that would be to pass a data object:

```
type:"GET",
url:"secret.aspx",
data: {
    plu : $("#Text1").val(),
    gh : $("#TextBox1").val(),
    sid : $("#TextBox2").val()
},
dataType: "html",
```

This encodes special characters to avoid breaking the key/value format. Alternatively you could keep them in the `url` but wrap each in `encodeURIComponent()`, which would have the same effect.

Comment: can this be retrieved using request.querystring @MrCode

Comment: Yes. jQuery converts it to a querystring behind the scenes. It's functionally the same as your original code but with the proper encoding included.

Comment: What happens if you navigate to the URL with your browser, passing some sample variables? to test the C# side.

Comment: OK so now open up the error console (F12), look at the Net/Network tab and watch the ajax request. See if there are any errors and see what the URL its requesting is.

Comment: 500
Internal Server Error

Comment: Remove the `processData : false`.

Comment: ok working fine but one problem response is not returned @MrCode

Comment: is it now showing a 200 OK response code (look in the console)?

Comment: i am using  respone.write("hello"),to get the data through sucess:function(data){
$('#div1').html(data)}

Comment: Should be `Response.Write("hello")` and `Resoonse.End()`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to serialize your form data into the 'data' option of the ajax method. Also, specify the type of request as GET if you want to use  the query string.

```
type: 'GET'
contentType: "text/html; charset=utf-8",
url:'secret.aspx',
processData: false,
dataType: "html",
data: $('#myForm').serialize(),
```